# Geom_line going crazy and not conneting points in a line plot with mean value in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was plotting means with categorical variables and divided into two groups.
Here is my code:

```
ggplot(data1, aes(x = edu_numer, y = fr_mean_ten, 
                      group = name, color = as.factor(name))) + 
  geom_point(stat = "summary", fun = "mean") +
  geom_line()
```

Here is the plot **without** the adding `geom_line()`:
[plot with points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kDvn.png)
Looks pretty good huh? I just need to connect these points.

But after adding geom_line its just random and confusing:
[plot with lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbNzw.png)

Btw I have tried using `aes()` line with `geom_line()`specify `group = name` or using `as.numeric` on my variables, none of them work.
Would appreciate any help or comments!

Comment: Try adding `stat = 'summary', fun = 'mean'` inside `geom_line` too. At the moment, it is drawing vertical lines joining all of the y values at each x value before moving onto the next x value.

Comment: @AllanCameron Omg it works!! Thank you so much! :DD

Answer (score 0):

We don't have your data, but it's easy enough to create a sample set with the same names and structure:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)

data1 <- data.frame(edu_numer = rep(1:5, each = 100),
                    fr_mean_ten = sample(0:10, 500, TRUE),
                    name = rep(rep(c('a', 'b'), each = 50), 5))
```

Now we can create a plot of just the average points, just like yours:

```
p <- ggplot(data1, aes(x = edu_numer, y = fr_mean_ten, 
                  group = name, color = as.factor(name))) + 
  geom_point(stat = "summary", fun = "mean") +
  guides(color = 'none')

p
```

[image]

And if we add a `geom_line`, the plot gets messed up, just like yours:

```r
p + geom_line()
```

[image]

Why is this? It's because the points you have generated in your `geom_point` layer are the *mean value* for each `edu_numer`, but the `geom_line` layer is joining *all the original points*, not the averaged points. If you want to join the averaged points, you need to tell `geom_line` that this is what you are trying to do, by also specifying `stat = "summary"`

```r
p + geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun = 'mean')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>